# How can I sort a particular column when triggered by a drop down menu on the client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

In my drop down menu If I Choose **Timestamp**, It should sort the TimeStamp in ascending/descending order or If I choose **Host** it should sort Host in ascending/descending order.

Currently I'm using Tablesorter plugin and it doesn't seem to work.

```
var value = $('#sourceDropdown :selected').text();
if(value == "TimeStamp"){
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({                  
        headers: {                     
            0: {                 
                sorter: true                                
            }
        }           
    });
    console.log("sorted"+ value);
}
else if(value=="Host") {
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({        
        headers: {                     
            1: {                 
                sorter: true                                
            }
        }           
    });
    console.log("sorted" +value);
}
else{
    console.log(value+" is not a valid option");
}
```

Comment: can you post your html as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like instead of telling it to sort, you are specifying which columns to allow sorting on. In order to sort the column you would use:

```
var sorting = [[0,0]]; 
// sort on the first column 
$("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
```

So in your case this should work:

```
var value = $('#sourceDropdown :selected').text();
        if(value == "TimeStamp"){
            var sorting = [[0,0]];
            $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
            console.log("sorted"+ value);
        }
        else if(value=="Host") {
            var sorting = [[1,0]];
            $("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
            console.log("sorted" +value);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(value+" is not a valid option");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks!! This pience of code works on JSFiddle but when I do it on my TextEditor, I get an error on the console saying **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined**, The web browser is pointing me to Jquery.tablesorter.min.js file.

Comment: That means you are trying to use the jquery function addClass on a variable that you think is an element but is actually not defined. Would have to see that part of the code to help you with that one.